# Can a missed shot still execute?

Tags: xcom-2

If you have a weapon which has both a Repeater and a Stock attached to it. Is there any chance that a missed shot will trigger the Repeater?

My assumption is that it will not as the actual shot did not hit, and the Repeater requires a hit in order to trigger, but it's a guess.

Reference: [Weapon upgrades](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_Upgrades_(XCOM_2))

Comment: It has never triggered on a missed shot for me. Afaik it can trigger if you miss a shot, then hit the second shot with an ability such as rapid fire though.

Comment: Doesn't relate directly to your question, but this reminds me of something I figured out the other day: the Stock doesn't work on Rapid Fire.

Comment: Repeater does trigger on poison and burning damage, so it should with stock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some investigation, it seems **Repeater only works on successful shots but if you have Stock then that damage can trigger Repeater bonus and execute the enemy**.

[image: animated GIF showing what's described above]

Animated GIF source, and more info at: https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/44oxea/stock_repeater_flawless_execution/

Comment: Can confirm - you can see it happen because the shot will animate completely missing, and then alien falls over dead.  Stock/Repeater is a great combo.

Answer (score 10):

It **used** to be possible for Stock+Repeater to trigger a "One-Miss Kill".

However the Alien Hunters patch (May 2016) has removed this possibility. So if your XCOM2 is auto-updating, this is **no longer possible**.